# Enter in information into terminal with BASH

Tags: linux, bash, volttron

I am working on trying to configure a Python based [IoT platform](https://pypi.org/project/volttron/) on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS edge device that requires a lot of redundant steps for entering information into the terminal.

For example I have to run these two commands below inside a Python virtual environment for device address number where I am showing device address number `11` as an example:

```
(volttron) geb@volttron:~$vctl config store platform.driver registry_configs/11.csv ./registry_configs/11.csv --csv
(volttron) geb@volttron:~$vctl config store platform.driver devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11 ./devices/11
```

And I have all these device addresses to do the same command but switch out the `11` for the correct address:

```
12035
15
21
25
30
36
4
5233
5237
5241
73017
9
1002
12028
12
16
22
26
31
37
5230
5234
5238
5242
73018
10
12032
13
19
23
27
33333
38
5231
5235
5239
6
7
1100
12033
14
20
24
29
34
39
5232
5236
5240
73005
8
```

I'm a first timer in Bash ... so I started this journey with: `$ nano make_reg_configs.sh`

And it looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "vctl config store platform.driver registry_configs/$1.csv ./registry_configs/$1.csv --csv"
echo "vctl config store platform.driver devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/$1 ./devices/$1"
```

So at least with this I think I can just do below for each one of my addresses:
`bash make_reg_configs.sh "11"`

That returns:

```
vctl config store platform.driver registry_configs/11.csv ./registry_configs/11.csv --csv
vctl config store platform.driver devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11 ./devices/11
```

Where it looks correct with just printing the string with echo but how would I enter the string into the terminal? I think I need something other than echo, would also be cool to just for loop through all the addresses as well if its not a hassle to incorporate that as well. Hopefully this all makes sense!

Comment: Just remove the echo and quotes and the command runs

Comment: well that was easy ! If you posted an answer Ill give you the green box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if I understood your final goal correctly (combining with the comment from diego)... if you save your addresses to a file called `addresses` in the same directory as your script this would do them all:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read address
do
  vctl config store platform.driver "registry_configs/${address}.csv" "./registry_configs/${address}.csv" --csv
  vctl config store platform.driver "devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/${address}" "./devices/${address}"
done<addresses
```

Comment: Thanks...what type of file extension should I save for `addresses` like a .json, .txt, or .csv? Sorry not a lot of wisdom here...

Comment: Linux doesn't need extensions at all (well, most programs don't) ... for your own sake you might call it `.lst` or `.txt`. Btw, giving a shell-script an extension is largely considered bad practice, more so when you use `bash` but name it `sh`.  @bbartling

Comment: P.S.: Thanks for the cleanup @konsolebox ... given the data I figured I could do without the quotes. In general it's of course much cleaner and safer to quote shell variables.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal run `$ bash make_reg_configs.sh 11`

```
#! /bin/bash

vctl config store platform.driver registry_configs/$1.csv ./registry_configs/$1.csv --csv
vctl config store platform.driver devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/$1 ./devices/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're wanting to have a convenient method of sending commands to screen while also executing them in obe call. You can create a convenient function for that.

```
function call {
    printf '%q ' "$@" # Prints args separately while also properly escaped to show which spaces are part of an argument
    echo # Add newline
    "$@" # Execute command
}

call vctl config store platform.driver "registry_configs/$1.csv" "./registry_configs/$1.csv" --csv
call vctl config store platform.driver "devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/$1" "./devices/$1"
```

Comment: Could you ever look at my answer which works...but ideally is it possible to include for loop with BASH and loop through a data structure of `addresses`?

Comment: @bbartling Tink just gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75348196/445221) for that. Is it what you want?